# node.js - post response is not waiting for callback to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I am working on node.js http server. The Server is connected to mongodb. I am requesting a post request to the server to get documents from mongodb. But the post response is not waiting for mongodb callback to complete. And therefore I am not getting required output on the client side. How to handle this?

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    if(request.method == "POST") { 
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log(chunk.toString());
            body += chunk;
        });
        request.on('end', function() {
            MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("We are not connected");
                }   
                else {
                    var sysInfo = db.collection('sysInfo');
                    var jsonObj = sysInfo.find().toArray();
                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                    response.end(jsonObj);
                }
            });
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error? I ask because the mongoose `connect` method callback just receives an `error` argument. So, when you do a `db.collection('sysInfo')`, you should get an error (db is `undefined`).

Comment: No. I don't get any error. But before the code reach response.end(jsonObj), post response is recieved at the client which has current html page as its content.

Comment: Got it. The answer provided by @JohnnyHK is perfect. I just got confused by the `mongoose` tag in your question, so I thought that you were trying to connect directly via `mongoose`. But then I realized that you're using the mongodb native driver.

Answer (score 2):

[`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray) is async, so it provides its results via callback rather than returning them.

So that part should be:

```
sysInfo.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end(docs);
});
```

Comment: This is not helping.
The reason being `request.on( 'end' ` ... is not waiting for `MongoClient.connect` callback  to complete.

So the problem is `MongoClient.connect` callback.

Comment: Or `response.end(docs)` is triggered after the `request.on( 'end' ...` returns data (the current html page) to the client.

Comment: Really Sorry. Problem solved. The Source of the problem was at a different. I provided incomplete information.  Thanks for your help.